# Typescript: problem with intersection of types containing a subset of specialized arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, union, intersection

I've a problem with intersection of types containing array members whose type is a subset of a specific type. It's harder to explain for me than simply show you the code.

This is a custom type

```js
type MyType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D';
```

This is the generic interface for the "base" object

```js
interface Base<A = {}, B = {}> {
  stringMember: string;
  arrayMember: MyType[];
  objectMember: {
    something: boolean;
  } & A;
  b: B;
}
```

I need to specialize arrayMember, objectMember and b memebers like so

```js
type A_Object_1 = {
  somethingElse: number;
};

type B_Object_1 = {
  aMember: boolean;
};

// Specialized type 1
type Specialized_1 = Base<A_Object_1, B_Object_1> & {
  arrayMember: ['A'];
};

// Specialized type 1 object, this is OK
const a_OK: Specialized_1 = {
  stringMember: 'hi',
  arrayMember: ['A'],
  objectMember: {something: true, somethingElse: 3},
  b: {aMember: true},
};
```

and so

```js
type A_Object_2 = {
  anything: boolean;
};

type B_Object_2 = {
  bMember: number;
};

type Specialized_2 = Base<A_Object_2, B_Object_2> & {
  arrayMember: ['B'];
};

// Specialized type 2 object, this is OK
const b_OK: Specialized_2 = {
  stringMember: 'hello',
  arrayMember: ['B'],
  objectMember: {something: true, anything: true},
  b: {bMember: 3},
};
```

I need an intersection type between Specialized_1 and Specialized_2, it should be like this

```js
{
  stringMember: string;
  arrayMember: ['A', 'B'];
  objectMember: {
    something: boolean;
    somethingElse: number;
    anything: boolean;
  };
  b: {aMember: boolean; bMember: number};
}
```

I do that the following (maybe wrong) way

```js
type Specialized_3 = Specialized_1 & Specialized_2;
```

The members that are objects are ok, since they contain both members from Specialized_1 & Specialized_2
Anyway there is a problem with the array type that is never, I see why, there is no intersection between ['A'] and ['B'],

```js
const c_Problem: Specialized_3 = {
  stringMember: 'hi there',
  arrayMember: ['A', 'B'], // Error here because arrayMember: never
  objectMember: {something: true, somethingElse: 3, anything: false}, // OK
  b: {aMember: false, bMember: 8}, // OK
};
```

It's been 2 days I'm thinking about that and I can't figure it out...
Moreover I find difficult to find the search keywords for this very specific problem.

Any help?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @AlekseyL.I made some progress, I can use `Omit` to omit `arrayMember` from the intersected object and than union it later "manually"

I can do this using a generic type like so:

```js
type PossibleSolution<T1 extends Base, T2 extends Base> = Omit<T1 & T2, 'arrayMember'> & {
  arrayMember: [T1['arrayMember'][number], T2['arrayMember'][number]];
};

type Specialized_Test = PossibleSolution<Specialized_1, Specialized_2>;

const d_OK: Specialized_Test = {
  stringMember: 'hi there',
  arrayMember: ['A', 'B'], // OK
  objectMember: {something: true, somethingElse: 3, anything: false}, // OK
  b: {aMember: false, bMember: 8}, // OK
};
```

The use of the generic type is for convenience since I need to reuse that here and there in my code.

This solution works, but only to intersect 2 objects, if I need to intersect 3 objects I have to delcare a different generic type

Now the problem is, how can I modify `PossibileSolution` generic type to intersect N `SpecializedObjects`?

Comment: The question is why `['A'] & ['B']` is `never` or how to work around this?

Comment: You could omit the `arrayMember` from intersection and resolve it manually `type Specialized_3 = Omit<Specialized_1 & Specialized_2, 'arrayMember'> & { arrayMember: [Specialized_1['arrayMember'][number], Specialized_2['arrayMember'][number]] };`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I know why ```['A'] & ['B']``` is ```never```, the question is how to workaround that... I need to test your solution, it seems that it can work

Comment: @AlekseyL. I made an adit, your hint was great, anyway I'm struggling with variadic generic types

Comment: It is possible if you'll provide a tuple of N types as a generic type parameter, but first you'll need to get rid of `arrayMember: MyType[];` in base or omit it when `Specialized_1` etc. are created. Currently the type of `Specialized_1['arrayMember']` is `MyType[] & ["A"]` which is not what you want I guess. Also `arrayMember: MyType[];` in base doesn't constraint `arrayMember` in derived (can be anything, not only `'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D'`)